WebdriverIO fetch Network logs: Not able to fetch network logs
I want to fetch network logs for failing requests, and I am running tests using native webdriver protocol, as runner: 'local'. Tried 'devtools' and other ways, but not able to fetch network logs. Is there a way that I get network logs from the chromedriver for the page where it's failing as 'Internal Server Error', also when the test has multiple tabs opened, want to fetch network logs from the tab where the test step is failing. I am using cucumber as the framework.
Tried 'devtools' but browser.cdp is deprecated, and also browser.logs, no idea on how to fetch network logs. I tried puppeteer but as I am using webdriver protocol to launch the chromedriver, and also using maxInstances to run the tests in parallel, puppeteer is not helping to fetch logs. I am looking for to fetch logs in the afterScenario when the test fails for that specific scenario.
